# How to change maxlength value in angular

Tags: angularjs, maxlength

I'm very new to angular. Im trying to change the value of maxlength from 300 to say 140 on click. The buttons are loaded using ng-repeat and the first one is the only one that's supposed to change the value to 140, the rest should go back to 300.

here's what I have in my controller:

```
//character counter
$scope.counter = function() {
    var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('.form-control'));
    myEl.attr('maxlength', '150');
};
```

and my html is this:

```
 <textarea data-ng-model="view.post.content" ng-trim="false" maxlength="340" class="form-control" style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: There should be no dom manipulation/traversal in a controller. Directives are for that purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `ng-maxlength` and bind it to a property on the scope, this will provide validation safety.

Example:-

```
 <textarea data-ng-model="view.post.content" ng-trim="false" 
            ng-maxlength="maxValue" class="form-control" 
            style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
```

If you want to really restrict then just use interpolation `maxlength={{maxValue}}`. i.e

```
 <textarea data-ng-model="view.post.content" ng-trim="false" 
            maxlength="{{maxValue}}" class="form-control" 
            style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
```

So initially `$scope.maxValue = 340` and then set inside the counter just the value of the property to 150.

**[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input#arguments)**

> **ngMaxlength
>   (optional)
>   number  :**
>   Sets maxlength validation error key if the value is longer than maxlength. Setting the attribute to a negative or non-numeric value, allows view values of any length.

**[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wE4ZV6?p=preview)**

Comment: All good but you don't need curly braces to reference a $scope variable in an `ng-maxlength`

Comment: @KirillSlatin yeah you are right, though document does not mention expression is allowed... it takes both. Both are valid as it is.

Comment: But it's really wierd to see an `ng-` directive with interpolation :) I think that's the way it's expected to be used

Comment: I checkout the demo, deff pointed me in the right direction, thanks! :). How would I make it do this on the first button loaded by ng-repeat?

Answer (score 2):

Use angular directive ng-maxlength

```
<textarea data-ng-model="view.post.content" ng-trim="false" ng-maxlength="{{len}}" class="form-control" style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
```

In your controller

```
//character counter
$scope.len = 300;
$scope.counter = function() {
  $scope.len = 150;
};
```

Comment: SWEET! got it to restrict and stuff. now, how would I set it up for the buttons? so that it only works on the first button loaded by ng-repeat?